# Advantages of running a local private recursive DNS server?

Tags: dns

My home network is "governed" by my ISP's router. Sometimes I saw strange packets outside my private IP range, appearing at my computers interfaces. Maybe something crossed VLANs, etc., I do not know (TV is in a separate VLAN). This pushed me to creating my own private network (also no security updates for ISP's router, DDNS clients do not work, etc.;), which would separate me from whatever is going on in ISP's network (with my own Wireguard server, etc.; I set it in DMZ, so I'm reachable from the Internet).

I also decided to somehow scatter my DNS searches (when not using a VPN). For example, to have some privacy from my ISP.

My reasoning was, if someone/something would be interested in someone's Internet activity and tried to obtain his/hers DNS history:

- when using only ISP's DNS servers, all my Internet adventures would be in a single place, ready for taking.
- The same apply if I would use 1.1.1.1 or something else.

But if I would run my own recursive server (BIND9) inside my private network, not reachable from the Internet:

- Only my DNS server, in my private network would know everything.
- My private DNS would only know root DNS servers (waiting a little bit longer for a query to return is not an issue for me).
- When using QNAME Minimization (`qname-minimization strict;`) intermediate DNS servers would only know parts of my queries.
- Only authoritative servers for my destinations would know my full query.
- Also, when an entry is in my private DNS cache, subsequent visits in a site/service would not show in public DNSes (because this IP is served from my cache; only the site/service would know that I went there).

I reason that in such situation if someone would try to find where I went on the Internet, it would be considerably harder -- my visits would be known only to sites/services I visited and to  DNS servers at the end of recursive query chain. So my full DNS history would be scattered in several, possibly dozens or hundreds of places.

Is this reasonable? Am I missing something? Are there any other advantages/disadvantages of this approach? (running a private DNS is not a disadvantage for me ;))

Kind Regards, K.

Comment: Unless you're using secure DNS, it's trivial for your ISP to sniff your traffic and pull out and log the DNS queries you send out (unless they're going through theVPN). Unless you have multiple uplinks with different ISPs, they all go through one connection and can all be logged.

Comment: Yup, that is true, on a protocol level there is no encryption unless DoT, DoH. If ISPs log all the traffic on their routers or mirror uplinks and store/analyze the traffic somewhere, 53 is plain text. This shifts trust somewhere else, for example 1.1.1.1, which offers DoH if I remember correctly. `systemd-resolved` allow for DoT or DoH, so it might be a viable option. But, do you trust Cloudflare? Could you recommend something?

Comment: You might be interested to read http://www.circleid.com/posts/20201215-dns-oblivion/ ; not necessarily to apply right now any of the 2 mechanisms but to see more on the context, the threats and what to do against them. Another completely different option is to use multiple recursive nameservers to spread queries among them. For that, have a look at https://dnsprivacy.org/wiki/display/DP/DNS+Privacy+Daemon+-+Stubby for example, and the whole wiki there is full of resources.

Comment: @user What is "secure DNS"? It could be DNSSEC, which offers integrity protection and authentication but certainly not encryption of data in transit.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek DNS over TLS, for example.

Comment: @user Yes, I know, but "secure DNS" as you used is ambiguous.

Comment: Hmm, stubby basically offers DoT, which is currently supported by `systemd-resolved`. I read sometimes ago about ODoH, but I'm suprised that someone already implemented this -- Cloudflare. As is written in article, the only guarantee that ODoH works is that proxy and actual resolver do not cooperate. This adds trust issues that those partners do not collude. I'm wondering, if I trust Cloudflare that it is not colluding with its partners, I might go with DoT only. It would be weird if they somehow used our data in DoT or DoH servers, but not in ODoH with its partners.

Comment: Although SURF seems like a trustworhty cooperative.